# Confidence Interval from RandomForestRegressor in scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

scikit-learn has a quantile regression based confidence interval implementation for GBM ([example form the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html)).

Is there a reason why it doesn't provide a similar quantile based loss implementation for RandomForestRegressor?

Answer (score 2):

There is an scikit-learn compatible/compliant Quantile Regression Forest implementation that can be used to generate confidence intervals here: https://github.com/zillow/quantile-forest

Setup should be as easy as:

```
pip install quantile-forest
```

Then, as an example, to generate CIs on a full dataset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from quantile_forest import RandomForestQuantileRegressor
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X, y = datasets.fetch_california_housing(return_X_y=True)

qrf = RandomForestQuantileRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
kf.get_n_splits(X)

y_true = []
y_pred = []
y_pred_lower = []
y_pred_upper = []

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = (
        X[train_index], X[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]
    )

    qrf.set_params(max_features=X_train.shape[1] // 3)
    qrf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Get predictions at 95% prediction intervals and median.
    y_pred_i = qrf.predict(X_test, quantiles=[0.025, 0.5, 0.975])

    y_true = np.concatenate((y_true, y_test))
    y_pred = np.concatenate((y_pred, y_pred_i[:, 1]))
    y_pred_lower = np.concatenate((y_pred_lower, y_pred_i[:, 0]))
    y_pred_upper = np.concatenate((y_pred_upper, y_pred_i[:, 2]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

y_pred_interval = y_pred_upper - y_pred_lower
sort_idx = np.argsort(y_pred_interval)
y_true = y_true[sort_idx]
y_pred_lower = y_pred_lower[sort_idx]
y_pred_upper = y_pred_upper[sort_idx]

# Center data, with the mean of the prediction interval at 0.
mean = (y_pred_lower + y_pred_upper) / 2
y_true -= mean
y_pred_lower -= mean
y_pred_upper -= mean

plt.plot(y_true, marker=".", ms=5, c="r", lw=0)
plt.fill_between(
    np.arange(len(y_pred_upper)),
    y_pred_lower,
    y_pred_upper,
    alpha=0.2,
    color="gray",
)
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y_pred_lower, marker="_", c="0.2", lw=0)
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y)), y_pred_upper, marker="_", c="0.2", lw=0)
plt.xlim([0, len(y)])
plt.xlabel("Ordered Samples")
plt.ylabel("Observed Values and Prediction Intervals (Centered)")

plt.show()
```

[image: CIs for California housing dataset]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be contributed scikit-learn package (example copy pasted from there for RandomForestRegressor)

I had to install development version in order to have correct path to current scikit-learn by:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/forest-confidence-interval.git
```

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/forest-confidence-interval

Example (copy pasted from the link above):

```
# Regression Forest Example
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import sklearn.model_selection as xval
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import forestci as fci

# retreive mpg data from machine learning library
mpg_data = fetch_openml('autompg')

# separate mpg data into predictors and outcome variable
mpg_X = mpg_data["data"]
mpg_y = mpg_data["target"]

# remove rows where the data is nan
not_null_sel = np.invert(
    np.sum(np.isnan(mpg_data["data"]), axis=1).astype(bool))
mpg_X = mpg_X[not_null_sel]
mpg_y = mpg_y[not_null_sel]

# split mpg data into training and test set
mpg_X_train, mpg_X_test, mpg_y_train, mpg_y_test = xval.train_test_split(mpg_X, mpg_y,
                                                                         test_size=0.25,
                                                                         random_state=42)

# Create RandomForestRegressor
n_trees = 2000
mpg_forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_trees, random_state=42)
mpg_forest.fit(mpg_X_train, mpg_y_train)
mpg_y_hat = mpg_forest.predict(mpg_X_test)

# Plot predicted MPG without error bars
plt.scatter(mpg_y_test, mpg_y_hat)
plt.plot([5, 45], [5, 45], 'k--')
plt.xlabel('Reported MPG')
plt.ylabel('Predicted MPG')
plt.show()

# Calculate the variance
mpg_V_IJ_unbiased = fci.random_forest_error(mpg_forest, mpg_X_train,
                                            mpg_X_test)

# Plot error bars for predicted MPG using unbiased variance
plt.errorbar(mpg_y_test, mpg_y_hat, yerr=np.sqrt(mpg_V_IJ_unbiased), fmt='o')
plt.plot([5, 45], [5, 45], 'k--')
plt.xlabel('Reported MPG')
plt.ylabel('Predicted MPG')
plt.show()
```